# Routing issue with Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, yaml

I have to upgrade an application previously developed by other guys with Symphony 1.4.

Inside my action.class.php there are two different functions:

```
public function executeCreateTask(sfWebRequest $request) {...}
public function executeCreateEvent(sfWebRequest $request) {...}
```

and inside my routing.yml I have 2 routes:

```
evaluation_task_create:
 url:     /evaluation/:id/task/create
 class:   sfDoctrineRoute
 options: { model: Evaluation, type: object }
 param:   { module: evaluation, action: createTask, sf_format: html }
 requirements: { sf_method: post }
```

and

```
evaluation_event_create:
 url:     /evaluation/:evaluation_id/event/create
 class:   sfDoctrineRoute
 options: { model: CustomEvent, type: object }
 param:   { module: evaluation, action: createEvent, sf_format: html }
 requirements: { sf_method: post }
```

The url 
    http://www.mysite/evaluation/21/task/create works perfectly (Creates a new task)

The url 
    http://www.mysite/evaluation/21/event/create returns an 404 error.

Any idea why I have this routing issue?

Comment: Are you doing a GET or a POST request? Notice that your second route contains `requirements: { sf_method: post }`. If this is not the problem is your `debug` setting set to true? What is the extact error message you are getting?

Comment: The request is triggered by a form with POST method. I'm not getting any error, it simply jumps to the Symfony's 404 error page.

Comment: What does this error page say? Are you getting an  sfError404Exception` with a message like `Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/evaluation/21/event/create" (/).`?

Comment: I don't really know what an sfDoctrineRoute does, since I am using Propel but does an CustomEvent with primary key 21 exist in the database?

Comment: "Oops! Page Not Found, The server returned a 404 response." No errors on log files. 21 is the evaluation_id 's value. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think it's a routing error, but I did'nt understand why...

Comment: You should debug your app in dev env. Try the same action with the dev controller (maybe `/frontend_dev.php/`). And first of all, did you clear your cache after adding the new route? (`php symfony cc`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to debug further, since you are not getting an sfError404Exception. Have you set `debug` to true in your ApplicationConfiguration? You can do this in your webdispatcher for your `dev` environment.

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration(
    'backend',
    'dev',
    true
);
```

And in your application's `settings.yml`:

```
dev:
  error_reporting: <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>
  web_debug: true
```

And in your application's `factories.yml` make sure you have set

```
dev:
  logger:
    param:
      loggers:
        sf_web_debug:
          param:
            xdebug_logging: true
```

Comment: i get a  sfError404Exception :"Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/evaluation/event/create" (/)."

Comment: So you managed to solve your problem? Did you notice that `/evaluation/event/create` does not contain `:id`? Also make sure to disable debugging in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the `createEvent` action of your `evaluation` module, you have probably something like

```
 $this->evalution = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
```

To get the right object from the route, you need to use `:id` variable for the id of the object and specify the right model `Evaluation` and not `CustomEvent`. So try to change `evaluation_event_create` route to:

```
evaluation_event_create:
  url:     /evaluation/:id/event/create
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Evaluation, type: object }
  param:   { module: evaluation, action: createEvent, sf_format: html }
  requirements: { sf_method: post }
```

and clear your cache.

Comment: Maybe he wants to use the `CustomEvent`? I think by default all variables in the url are passed to the method retrieving such an object from the database.